# How to display uploaded images in pdf using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ruby, pdf, carrierwave, wkhtmltopdf, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using Carrierwave to upload images in rails4.

In the html view page the image is showing. But, when generating the pdf, from this view, the image is not showing.Instead , a blank box is showing.

From the view, while inspecting the path is showing as below:

```
<img alt="Small images" src=" http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload_ 
files/6/student/image/1/small_images.jpg">
```

The code i used is:

```
<%=image_tag Student.find(id).image_url(:small) %>
```

If the image is stored in app/assets/images, then the images will appear.But, i need to upload the image in this location only.

Can u pls help...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it with php Laravel this way >>

```
<img alt="Small images" src="{{base_path().'path/to'image.jpg'}}">
```

I have no experiences with Ruby , but try to find something similar.